# How can you track the realtime user data (Gender, age, etc) through analytics when user land on your website?

Tags: google-analytics, content-management-system, analytics, google-analytics-api

When a visitor lands on my website i want to track the user data such as age, gender, etc. so that i can personalize the page he/she is viewing. Is there any analytics API or GA script available?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to go through the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Additionally read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Since this is tagged with google-analytics I can at least answer that this does not work with GA for a variety of reasons.

- demographic data is not available in realtime with GA the realtime
- realtime API has usage limits that would quickly be exceeded by such use
- in GA demographic data is not available for small user segments (including segments of one), AFAIK for privacy reasons

Any system would need a data source for demographic information. If you're not Google or Facebook with a large advertising network then you usually need to collect the data yourself and feed it to your analytics system (I think e.g. Mixpanel works like this).